# Flutter error in back/forward navigation for webview

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, webview

I'm trying to navigate on my webview but especially on some sites e.g Twitter, and Instagram it stays stuck (You can see the message in the log section). But it works for google, e.a.

Let's consider that I'm running "loadUrl()" for twitter.com again and again. It can load the site successfully. Then I loaded google.com. After that, I tapped the navigationBack which is running goBack() func. It stucks like in logs. But for vice versa, I can go back to google.com

Here are my code snippets:

```
  Future<void> goToSite(String siteUrl) async {
    await _controller.future;
    final WebViewRequest request = WebViewRequest(
      uri: Uri.parse(url),
      method: WebViewRequestMethod.get,
    );
    await _webController.loadRequest(request);
  }
```

```
     Widget browser() {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://${_urlController.text.toLowerCase()}',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        if (!_controller.isCompleted) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
          _webController = webViewController;
        }
        print("web created");
      },
      onProgress: (int progress) {
        print('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
        if (progress == 100) {
          notify();
        }
      },
      navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
        print('allowing navigation to $request');
        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
      onPageStarted: (String url) {
        print('Page started loading: $url');
      },
      onPageFinished: (String url) {
        print('Page finished loading: $url');
      },
      gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
      backgroundColor: const Color(0x00000000),
    );
  }
```

I'm using this method to navigate:

```
  await _webController.goBack();
  await _webController.goForward();
```

When I tapped goBack I got this repetitive error:

```
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x152efaee0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=10293, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x152efaf40 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID=10293, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
flutter: Page started loading: https://mobile.twitter.com/
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x152efb060 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=10294, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x152efb0c0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID=10294, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
flutter: Page started loading: https://mobile.twitter.com/
```

I couldn't find the reason. How can I fix this issue?